# Want to add photos from gallery into a GridView (Android Studio)

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

My goal is to be able to click an "upload image" and have it appear on a gridview similar to an instagram feed on one's profile (not the scrolling feed, the grid feed). Honestly I am very lost and have simply been trying different methods I found on sites online but nothing really has worked.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private ArrayList<Image> items = new ArrayList<Image>();

    ImageView uploadedImage;
    Button bUploadImage;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bUploadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUploadImage);
        bUploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,R.id.bUploadImage,items));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bUploadImage:
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            uploadedImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            Image i = new Image();
            i.setURI(selectedImage);
            items.add(i);

        }
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Image> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Image> items;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Image> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        mContext = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        if (position == 0)
            imageView.setImageURI(items.get(position).getURI());
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Image class:

```
public class Image {
    private Uri imgURI;

    public Uri getURI(){
        return imgURI;
    }

    public void setURI(Uri imgURI){
        this.imgURI = imgURI;
    }

}
```

I have seen many methods of displaying images on a grid but none using images from a gallery. In my code above, I attempt to pass in the Uri of the image from gallery to the adapter, but I am confused as to how adapters and it all works. I am a complete beginner in Android Studio. Any guidance is helpful, thank you!

Comment: try this- http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Comment: Can you please edit your question? It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In place of following line in onCreate

```
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,R.id.bUploadImage,items));
```

Create class level adapter

```
private ImageAdapter adapter;
```

and in onCreate()

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(this,R.id.bUploadImage,items)
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In onActivityResult after item.add call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged.

Comment: I am not able to add the call "adapter.notifyDatasetChanged" in the MainActivity, not sure why.

Comment: are you calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() (this is exact spelling, try this) otherwise give me some detail.